# Unfortunately app has stopped, permission allow or deny after allow it works but in the begining i get pop up that my app has stopped

Tags: android, android-camera, runtime-permissions

I am trying to request camera permission but whenever i run my project I get my app has stopped pop up at first and then it shows allow or deny option if i click never show again option it wont let me press allow. And if I allow my app to run it exist and I again have to open app. But the issue will be disappear and my app will run perfectly in next attempt.. here is the logcat

> 07-26 18:41:56.080 3003-3003/com.example.android.camerapermission E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                       Process: com.example.android.camerapermission, PID: 3003
>                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.camerapermission/com.example.android.camerapermission.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
>                                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.(Camera.java:495)
>                                                                                           at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:356)
>                                                                                           at com.example.android.camerapermission.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

and Here is my MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.android.camerapermission;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;

import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.test.mock.MockPackageManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nispok.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;


    ImageButton imageButton;
    Camera camera;
    Camera.Parameters parameters;
    boolean isflash = false;
    boolean isOn = false;


    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 0);
            }
        }
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
            ;

        {
            camera = Camera.open();
            parameters = camera.getParameters();
            isflash = true;

        }


        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (isflash) {

                    if (!isOn) {
                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);
                        camera.startPreview();
                        isOn = true;

                    } else {
                        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        camera.setParameters(parameters);
                        camera.stopPreview();
                        isOn = false;
                    }


                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Error.....");
                    builder.setMessage("Flashlight is not available on this device...");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    public void showCamera(View view) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Show that camera button is clicked. Checking permission.");
        /**
         * Include camera permission and
         * check if camera is available in phone or not
         */
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Camera permission is not granted yet
            requestCameraPermission();
        } else {
            //Camera is available, show the camera preview

            Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission has granted, displaying camera preview");
            showCameraPreview();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Request the Camera Permission again in the case of user mistakenly denied permission.
     * Create a SnackBar that will prompt the user to grant the permission, otherwise it is requested direcly.
     */

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        Log.i(TAG, " Camera permission is still not granted. Requesting permission.");

        //Start (camera_permission_request)
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // show an additional request to the user if the permission was not granted earlier.


        } else {
            //Camera permission has not been granted yet. Request directly.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
        // END (camera_permission_request)
    }


    private void showCameraPreview() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, CameraPreviewFragment.newInstance())
                .commit();
    }


    /**
     * Receiving permission after granted
     */

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            //Begin request (permission_result)
            //Recieved permission result for the camera permission.
            Log.i(TAG, "Request for Camera permission is received. ");

            //Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Camera permission is safely granted, now you can preview.
                Log.i(TAG, "Camera permission has succesfully granted, preview is being displayed");


            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission is not granted.");

                // Finish(permission_result)
            }

            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isflash = false;

        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Camera permission is already set in Manifest.xml.

Comment: Yes. I am testing this on my phone which is 7.1.2 and I am testing in 6.0 in emulator. Same issue.

Comment: I think you have to request for Read and Write ExternalStorage permission to use camera. because after capturing when camera will store image you have to take Write Permission.

This example also using Write Permission(not runtime but in manifiest) - https://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose camera open call in a try catch.

```
try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
```

From the Android Developer Website,

```
Caution: Always check for exceptions when using Camera.open(). Failing to check for exceptions if the camera is in use or does not exist will cause your application to be shut down by the system.
```

Comment: The issue still appears. unfortunately I couldn't paste the code because of character limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down, this is your code:

```
1.  if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))
2.      ;
3.  {
        camera = Camera.open();
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        isflash = true;
    }
```

This is what happens.

```
1.  // If the system has a camera flash
2.  // Do nothing. The condition terminates here.
3.  // Open camera in any case.
```

To fix it, remove the stray semicolon on line 2, and mind your semicolons in the future.

Comment: I removed it but the issue still appears.

Comment: You check for permissions but then try to open the camera no matter the result of permission check. There's an else block around the camera missing. Or maybe switch it around. Why even ask for permission if the device has no camera?